# Python Unicode Encoding

Tags: python, unicode, encode, argparse

I am using `argparse` to read in arguments for my python code. One of those inputs is a title of a file [`title`] which can contain Unicode characters. I have been using `22少女時代22` as a test string.

I need to write the value of the input `title` to a file, but when I try to convert the string to `UTF-8` it always throws an error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 2: ordinal
>           not in range(128)

I have been looking around and see I need my string to be in the form `u"foo"` to call `.encode()` on it.

When I run `type()` on my input from `argparse` I see:

```
<type 'str'>
```

I am looking to get a response of:

```
<type 'unicode'>
```

How can I get it in the right form?

**Idea:**

Modify `argparse` to take in a `str` but store it as a unicode string `u"foo"`:

```
parser.add_argument(u'title', metavar='T', type=unicode, help='this will be unicode encoded.')
```

This approach is not working at all. Thoughts?

**Edit 1:**

Some sample code where `title` is `22少女時代22`:

```
inputs = vars(parser.parse_args())
title = inputs["title"]
print type(title)
print type(u'foo')
title = title.encode('utf8') # This line throws the error
print title
```

Comment: What encoding is your input data?

Comment: @MarkTolonen Ok, I will edit my post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like your input data is in [SJIS encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) (a legacy encoding for Japanese), which produces the byte 0x8f at position 2 in the bytestring:

```
>>> '22少女時代22'.encode('sjis')
b'22\x8f\xad\x8f\x97\x8e\x9e\x91\xe322'
```

(At Python 3 prompt)

Now, <del>I'm guessing that</del> to "convert the string to UTF-8", you used something like

```
title.encode('utf8')
```

The problem is that `title` is actually a bytestring containing the SJIS-encoded string. Due to a design flaw in Python 2, bytestrings can be directly `encode`d, and it assumes the bytestring is ASCII-encoded. So what you have is conceptually equivalent to

```
title.decode('ascii').encode('utf8')
```

and of course the `decode` call fails.

You should instead explicitly decode from SJIS to a Unicode string, before encoding to UTF-8:

```
title.decode('sjis').encode('utf8')
```

---

As Mark Tolonen pointed out, you're probably typing the characters into your console, and it's your console encoding is a non-Unicode encoding.

So it turns out your `sys.stdin.encoding` is [`cp932`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932), which is Microsoft's variant of SJIS. For this, use

```
title.decode('cp932').encode('utf8')
```

You really *should* set your console encoding to the standard UTF-8, but I'm not sure if that's possible on Windows. If you do, you can skip the decoding/encoding step and just write your input bytestring to the file.

Comment: The OP can execute `import sys; print sys.stdin.encoding` at a console to determine the input encoding, or just use `title.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)`.

Comment: On Python 2.7.2 I received `cp932` from `print sys.stdin.encoding;`

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Hmm. Calling `print title.decode('cp932').encode('utf8')` prints `22蟆大･ｳ譎ゆｻ｣22` which is a odd mutation of the input string. Thoughts?

Comment: The terminal is cp932, so it won't display UTF-8 properly.  To view it, you'd need to write the encoded string to a file and read it in a viewer that supports UTF-8.

Comment: @Morrowind789: The output of that is UTF-8 encoded. That statement writes it to your CP932-encoded console, so it gets interpreted as CP932, resulting in mojibake. In particular, this matches your output (Python 3 console):
`'22少女時代22'.encode('utf8').decode('cp932')`
`'22蟆大･ｳ譎ゆｻ｣22'`

Comment: Wait I see that was the encode to `utf8` causing the mutation. I was made aware of this by following the answer from Mark below.

Comment: @Morrowind789: No. What's causing the mutation is decoding the UTF-8-encoded string as though it were CP932.

Comment: My commandline is doing the decoding since my sys.stdin.encoding is cp932 but the text was encoded via utf8 thanks to .encode('utf8') so the result is "mojibake". Yes?

Answer (score 4):

Setting `type=unicode` is like using `unicode(arg)` which defaults to decoding with `ascii` on Python 2.X.  If running from the console, `sys.stdin.encoding` is the encoding used for input, so something like:

```
inputs = vars(parser.parse_args())
title = inputs["title"]
print type(title)
print type(u'foo')
title = title.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
print title
```

Something that should work no matter the encoding on Windows is the `mbcs` encoding, which represents the current encoding used by non-Unicode Windows programs.  That seems to be what `argparse` is using, because I `sys.stdin.encoding` is the *OEM* console encoding which isn't always the same as the Windows encoding.  On US Windows, `cp437` is the console OEM encoding and `cp1252` is the Windows encoding:

```
import argparse
import codecs
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(u'title', metavar='T', type=str, help='this will be unicode encoded.')
opts = parser.parse_args()
title = opts.title.decode('mbcs')
with codecs.open('out.txt','w',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    f.write(title)
```

`out.txt` should show the original input in Notepad.

The `utf-8-sig` encoding writes the so-called byte order mark (BOM) that Windows likes at the beginning of UTF-8 files.  `utf-8` can be used if that is not desired, but Notepad likes it.

Comment: Good point that you can use `title.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)`.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail, turns out it doesn't work on US Windows.  I added a note as to why.  Some Windows systems don't have the same encoding for console and non-console programs.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I can confirm this works on my box running Win7 x64. [See Image](http://i.imgur.com/Wu29q.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

So, this actually works for me:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(u'title', metavar='T', type=str, help='this will be unicode encoded.')
opts = parser.parse_args()
print opts.title.decode('utf8')
```

My terminal emulator (OS X Terminal.app) uses UTF-8. If your terminal is not configured for UTF-8 operation, then it won't work (and then it's a terminal problem, not a Python issue).

Comment: Hmm interesting. Let me recheck on my environment. I am using 2.7.2.