# Encoding issue when scraping chinese text into csv with python

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble scraping chinese text into a csv. I've tried 3 different things (commented in the code), but the csv still contains only garbled text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
#import codecs

url="http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XOTU2Nzc3NDYw.html"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url,context=gcontext).read()#.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
title= soup.findAll('h1', { "class" : "title" })[0].string#.encode('utf-8')
outputfile='.../file.csv'
fd = open(outputfile,'a')
#fd = codecs.open(outputfile, "a", "utf-8")    
fd.write(title)
fd.close()
```

Comment: You should say what gives `urllib2.urlopen(url,context=gcontext).headers.get('content_type')`. It should give hints on the actual page encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main page is encoded in utf8. I could load it that way:

```
>>> url="http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XOTU2Nzc3NDYw.html"
>>> page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
>>> page.headers.get('content-type')
'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
>>> txt = page.read().decode('utf8')
>>> print txt

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
...
```

So it declares both at HTTP level and in an html meta that it is utf8 encoded and seems to decode nicely in utf8.

I went one step further:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(txt)
>>> title= soup.findAll('h1', { "class" : "title" })[0].string.encode('utf-8')
>>> print repr(title)
'\n\t\t\xe8\xa7\x86\xe9\xa2\x91: \xe3\x80\x90\xe9\xac\xbc\xe9\x97\x95\xe4\xb8\x83\xe7\x9a\x87\xe3\x80\x91\xe5\x90\x84\xe5\x9b\xbd\xe8\xb7\x91\xe9\x85\xb7\xe9\xab\x98\xe6\x89\x8b\xe6\x9e\x81\xe9\x99\x90\xe8\xb7\x91\xe9\x85\xb7\xe6\xb7\xb7\xe5\x89\xaa'
```

So `title` is a perfectly correct utf8 encoded byte string, because I could print it and it gave chinese characters.

If the file seems to contain garbage, it is simply because you open it with a non utf8 capable editor, or forgot to put it in utf8 mode.

Comment: You're correct. I opened the csv with Excel, which I assumed would read utf8 correctly by default, but it doesn't.Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

This is because You try to decode\encode by utf-8, You should use other Unicode instead. Link to page: http://pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/

Comment: Thanks. I thought 'utf-8' was unicode... can you give me a hint as to how to change my code? Simply changing 'utf-8' to 'Unicode' gets me "unknown encoding"

Comment: 'utf=8' is an encoding.  The website may be using a different encoding.  Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764589/python-unicode-encoding

Comment: the page I'm scraping contains <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> in the source. So it doesn't look like it's the wrong encoding...?